# Azure servicebus python - how to send a bunch of messages

Tags: python, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

To avoid errors when I have to send a group of messages that is larger than max size, I wrote a class useful to send bunch of messages.

Well, first of all would be wonderful if somebody could show me an example that explains how to avoid this problem.

Trying to solve the problem by myself I found extremely hard understanding the size of the message (`ServiceBusMessage`).

The method `sb_msg.message.get_message_encoded_size()` it’s the nearest thing of what I need.

Do you know how to calculate the message size?

```
def send_as_json(self, msg, id_field=None, size_in_bytes=262144):
        if isinstance(msg, list):
            payload = self.topic_sender.create_message_batch(size_in_bytes)
            for m in msg:
                try:
                   # add a message to the batch
                   sb_msg = ServiceBusMessage(json.dumps(m), message_id=m.get(id_field, uuid.uuid4()), content_type='application/json')
                   total_size = payload.size_in_bytes + sb_msg.message.get_message_encoded_size()
                   if total_size > size_in_bytes:
                        _log.info(f'sending partial batch of {payload.size_in_bytes} bytes')
                        self.send_service_bus_message(payload)
                        payload = self.topic_sender.create_message_batch(size_in_bytes)
                   payload.add_message(sb_msg)
                except ValueError as e:
                    # ServiceBusMessageBatch object reaches max_size.
                    # New ServiceBusMessageBatch object can be created here to send more data.
                    raise Exception('', e)
            self.send_service_bus_message(payload)
        else:
            sb_msg = ServiceBusMessage(json.dumps(msg), message_id=msg.get(id_field, uuid.uuid4()), content_type = 'application/json')
            self.send_service_bus_message(sb_msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure ServiceBus - Python:
Below code will give you a insight on how to send batch of messages:

```
def send_batch_message(sender):
# create a batch of messages
batch_message = sender.create_message_batch()
for _ in range(10):
    try:
        # add a message to the batch
        batch_message.add_message(ServiceBusMessage("Message inside a ServiceBusMessageBatch"))
    except ValueError:
        # ServiceBusMessageBatch object reaches max_size.
        # New ServiceBusMessageBatch object can be created here to send more data.
        break
# send the batch of messages to the queue
sender.send_messages(batch_message)
print("Sent a batch of 10 messages")
```

For more detail information you can visit below Microsoft docs, In this link we have clear information of sending messages as single, list or batch: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues)

**How to find the size of message:**

With the help of below function we can find the size of the message in bytes:

```
 Import sys
 sys.getsizeof(variable_name)  #this gives us the bytes occupied by the variable.
```

To check the max_size_in_bytes of a batch, we can simply print below message

```
batch_message = sender.create_message_batch() # Step1
batch_message.add_message(ServiceBusMessage("Message we want to add")) #Step2 Add message to the batch in a loop.
print(batch_message) #Step3 We will get the output as below as yellow after printing, below is the output:
```

Output:

> ServiceBusMessageBatch(max_size_in_bytes=1048576, message_count=10)